# How to denote this relationship between two domains of a function

Tags: functions, notation

Say I have a function $\boldsymbol f: X \to Y$ with, say, $X, Y \in \mathbb [0, 1]^n$. The domain $X$ is a hypercube $X_1 \times X_2 \times \cdots \times X_n$ with $X_i \in \mathbb [0, 1]$.

I want to restrict the function to $A \subset X$ such that for a $\boldsymbol x$ drawn from either $A$ or $X$ each component $x_i$ can have the same range of values. That is $A$ spans the hypercube $X$ from side to side along each dimension.

E.g. for the 2d case, an example of what $A$ might and must not look like is:

[image: Examples of an A fulfilling the constraint or violating it]

My question is now whether there's a concise and clear way to denote this relationship between $A$ and $X$? Maybe something along the lines of each of their components having the same support?

Comment: I'd simply say: for and $w\in [0,1]$ and any $k: 1\le k \le n$ there is an $x=(x_1,x_2,.....,x_n) \in A$ so that $x_k = w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\,n\in\mathbb N\,$ and $\,I=\big\{1,2,\ldots,n\big\}\,.$

The relationship between $\,A\,$ and $\,X\,$ could be denoted in the following way:

$\forall\,i\in I,\,\forall\,x_i\in X_i\,,\;\forall\,j\in I\setminus\{i\}\;\exists x_j\in X_j\;$ such that $\;\left(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\right)\in A\;.$